The function ggscatmat {GGally} is working properly? I put corMethod="spearman" and print "pearson"
The function ggscatmat {GGally} is working properly? I put corMethod="spearman" and the result is "pearson".
This is an example:
x<-c(1,2,4,3,5)
y<-c(2,-4,8,6,1)
db<-data.frame(x,y)

cor(db$x,db$y,method = "pearson")
cor(db$x,db$y,method = "spearman")
cor(db$x,db$y,method = "kendall")

library(GGally)
ggscatmat(db,alpha=0.8,corMethod="spearman")

